# Magento 1.9 Syntax error | Module conflict

Tags: magento-1.9, helper, conflict

I had a module conflict so decided to create a "temp" class and use it as a "extender". First check if module is enabled and if it is extend using the "temp" class, if it is not, extend the core class.

Here is my code:

```
8  if (Mage::Helper('Core')->isModuleEnabled('AW_Autorelated')) {
9   Amasty_Rules_Model_SalesRule_Rule_Condition_Product_Subselect_Temp extends AW_Autorelated_Model_Salesrule_Rule_Condition_Product_Subselect {}
10 }
11 else {
12  Amasty_Rules_Model_SalesRule_Rule_Condition_Product_Subselect_Temp extends Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Subselect {}
13 }
14
15 class Amasty_Rules_Model_SalesRule_Rule_Condition_Product_Subselect extends Amasty_Rules_Model_SalesRule_Rule_Condition_Product_Subselect_Temp
16 {
```

Using `n98-magerun` and running `dev:module:rewrite:conflict` command I get following error:

```
[~]$ mr_devsitexxx dev:module:rewrite:conflict

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'extends' (T_EXTENDS) in /domains/devsitexxx/http/app/code/local/Amasty/Rules/Model/SalesRule/Rule/Condition/Product/Subselect.php on line 9
```

Also line 9

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"class" is missing before the class name

Comment: I clearly can't see properly... Thanks mate!

Comment: In the future, if you get syntax errors, please look at the line **before** the "unexpected token". This will save you the round-trip to StackExchange ;-)

Comment: I read it like 20 times :D Could see it... sorry to bother you, I think I need some rest :p Thank you for advice too!